# Difference between timezones with Carbon

Tags: php, timezone, php-carbon

Time in CEST = UTC time+2h
but my code showing only 1h and I don't know why... (you can test it [here](http://phpio.net/tools/carbon) )

```
require 'Carbon/Carbon.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;

$timestamp = '2018-04-06 14:30:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'UTC');
var_dump($date);
//{ ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-04-06 14:30:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } 
$date->tz('CEST');
var_dump($date);
//{ ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-04-06 15:30:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(2) ["timezone"]=> string(4) "CEST" }
```

Comment: Show us the results of the `var_dump`?

Comment: It also depends on the initial timezone of your PHP settings.

Comment: added results of `var_dump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `CEST` is not a supported timezone in PHP, and can therefore exhibit ["undefined behaviour"](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). I suspect it's being interpreted as `CET`, which is UTC+1.

If you use a specific geographical identifier instead, such as `Europe/Berlin`, it should present the correct result (i.e. +2 hours from UTC). Try:

```
$date->tz('Europe/Berlin');
```

See https://3v4l.org/c4lve